# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Person'

Tags: ios, core-data

```
-(void)action_addInformation:(id)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"add person information");
        @try {

             AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];

            NSEntityDescription *entityDescription=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            NSManagedObject *newPerson=[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
            [newPerson setValue:firstNameTxtField.text forKey:@"firstname"];
            [newPerson setValue:lastNameTxtField.text forKey:@"lastname"];

            NSError *error;
            [context save:&error];
            NSLog(@"Information added successfully");

        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"%@",exception);
        } @finally {

        }
        }
```

I used Core Data for a table view with objC Language. It can launch successfully, but after clicking Done button in AddView, there is an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Person'*

Comment: you `context` is nil, check why it's `nil`?

Comment: Check your app delegate's code and put breakpoints where context is being created, check wether persistence store coordinator is being created successfully